# Testing method for in-app purchases with the Google-play store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I hope everyone is having a good new year so far.

I'm a first-time developer of an android app. The application is free but has an in-app subscription purchase. I've created a release in the Internal Testing track within the Google Play Developers console and, from what I've gathered, my implementation of the Billing library should work, but I'm writing to ask if there's anyway to test the feature here and now, or will I have to wait for google to review the app and send it back for testing (I'm the only tester listed in the test track).

If there isn't any way to test the full in-app purchase feature without Google having approved the app (which I would understand), would someone be willing to explain the general process to me as I haven't been able to find too much information online.

1. Will I (as the only tester listed) receive an email prompting me to test the app, at which point I'll be able to download a new APK which will be able to communicate with Google Play?
2. How long does the approval process really usually take?

I apologize that this question lacks code, but it really is a "Google processes" question more than an android or java one.

Thank you.

Comment: Usually when you submit an app take some time (not sure but few days for new app) then you should get an email saying it has been released at which point you can navigate to the test url and download the app. As you are the developer you can subscribe/purchase with a test card provided by google play.

Comment: Thank you! As simple as it is, that clarity is exactly what I needed.

Comment: I'm on the second day of waiting for internal testing availability with Pending publication status. @Journeywork , how long has it taken for you?